# Assign dynamically generated image to ToggleButton.Content

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I have to put dynamically generated image

```
var img = new Bitmap(..);
// draw something on img canvas ...
```

To the ToggleButton background. When I assign generated image to ToggleButton.Content property I see "System.Drawing.Bitmap" string, not the image itself. It looks like ToString() method is used for Content property. How can I show generated image instead?

Comment: I think you will need to override the default ControlTemplate with one of your own to do this... OR find out if the Togglebutton has a DataTemplate field and use that instead :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If WPF does not have an appropriate converter it just calls the `ToString()` method, the Bitmap format is unsuitable, what you normally want to use is an `Image` with a source that is a `BitmapImage`, there are several ways to do conversions between the different formats.
Here is one method that does a conversion from `Bitmap` to `BitmapImage`:

```
public static BitmapImage BitmapToBitmapImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    BitmapImage bImg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

    bImg.BeginInit();
    bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
    bImg.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    bImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.Default;
    bImg.EndInit();

    ms.Close();

    return bImg;
}
```

Note that `ImageFormat.Png` is slower than uncompressed formats but it retains the transparency if there is any.
Now you should be able to use this as the Source of an Image control and this Image control as the content of the button.

Answer (score 2):

"Content" property is concerned with what you write on the surface of the ToggleButton. You need to initialize the "Background" property of the UI element. Here is one example:

```
        PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Bgr32;
        int width = 200;
        int height = 200;
        int rawStride = (width * pf.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
        byte[] rawImage = new byte[rawStride * height];

        // Initialize the image with data.
        Random value = new Random();
        value.NextBytes(rawImage);

        // Create a BitmapSource.
        BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, pf, null, rawImage, rawStride);

        ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
        myToggleButton.Background = imgBrush;
```

I created the image using the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(VS.85).aspx